# java multithread performance on sync object

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to test the multithreading performance with sync'ed object. However,
with 1 thread or with 16 threads the execution time is the same.

The rest of the code is here.
https://codeshare.io/5oJ6Ng

```
  public void run() {
        start = new Date().getTime();
        System.out.println(start);

            while (threadlist.size() < 9000) { //16 or more

                  //  try{Thread.sleep(100);}catch (Exception f){}

                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        while (add(1,3) < 1000000);
                        end = new Date().getTime();
                        System.out.println((end-start));
                    }
                });
                    threadlist.add(t);

               while( threadlist.iterator().hasNext()){
                   threadlist.iterator().next().start();
                   try{threadlist.iterator().next().join();}catch (Exception a){}
               }
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code. First:

```
public void run() {
       while (true) {
            add(1, 3);
        }
 }
```

Those threads never stop working, I would suggest rewriting your logic to:

```
   public void (run) {
        while(add(1,3) < 1000000);
        System.out.println("now 1000000");
   }

   public int add(int val1, int val2) {
        synchronized (this) {
            this.sum1 += val1;
            this.sum2 += val2;
            return this.sum1 + this.sum2;
            }
        }
    }
```

You start the threads, but you never call `join`, eventually you will need to do that.

You are only creating 1 thread instead of the 16 that you wanted:

```
if (threadlist.size() < 1)
```

you want

```
if (threadlist.size()  < 16)
```

Finally, do not expect any performance gain with this code, since you are synchronizing on the object:

```
synchronized (this){...}
```

So basically your `add` method is being run sequentially and not in parallel, since threads will wait on synchronized (this) and call only run on at the time inside your the block of code wrapped by the synchronized statement.

Try to measure your time by adding `start = new Date().getTime();` before the parallel region, and `end = new Date().getTime();` after.

You can simply your code to:

```
public void run() {
    start = new Date().getTime();
    System.out.println(start);
    while (threadlist.size() < 16) {
         Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
              while (add(1,3) < 1);
              System.out.println("now 1000000");
        });
        threadlist.add(t);
    }
    threadlist.forEach(Thread::start);
    
    threadlist.forEach(thr-> {
            try { thr.join();} 
            catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
     });
     end = new Date().getTime();
     System.out.println("Time taken : "+(end-start));

     public int add(int val1, int val2) {
            synchronized (this) {
                this.sum1 += val1;
                this.sum2 += val2;
                return this.sum1 + this.sum2;
                }
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've significantly updated your code since @dreamcrash answered.

The current version has the following issues:

> ```
> while( threadlist.iterator().hasNext()) {
>    threadlist.iterator().next().start();
>    try{threadlist.iterator().next().join();}catch (Exception a){}
>  }
> ```

This starts a thread and then will immediately sit around, twiddling its thumbs until that thread is completely done with its job, and will then fire up another thread. **Therefore, you never more than 1 active thread at a time**.

> `catch (Exception a){}`

You're learning / debugging, and you do this? Oh dear. Don't. Don't ever write a catch block like that. Update your IDE or your muscle memory: The right "I dont want to think about exceptions right now" code is `catch (Exception a) { throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled", a);}`. To be clear, this isn't the problem, but this is such a bad habit, it needed to be called out.

> `synchronized (this) {`

I really doubt if you fix the 'join' issue I mentioned earlier this will ever run any faster. This synchronized call is important, but it also causes so much blockage that you're likely to see zero actual benefit here.

More generally the calculation you are trying to speed up involves an accumulator.

accumulator is another word for 'parallelising is utterly impossible here, it is hopeless'.

The algorithm cannot involve accumulators if you want to parallellize it, which is what multithreading (at least, if the aim of the multiple threads is to speed things up) is doing. This algorithm cannot be made any faster with threads. period.

Usually algorithms can be rewritten to stop relying on accumulators. But this is clearly an exercise to see an effect, so, just find anything else, really. Don't lock on a single object for the entire calculation: Only one thread is ever actually doing work, all the 999 others are just waiting.